# How make logic OR between vertex Indexes in Titan 1.0 / TP3 3.01 using predicate Text

Tags: titan, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

During my migration from TP2 0.54 -> TP3 titan 1.0 / Tinkerpop 3.01

I'm trying to build gremlin query which make "logical OR" with Predicate Text , between properties on different Vertex indexes

Something like:

-------------------   PRE-DEFINED ES INDEXES: ------------------

```
tg = TitanFactory.open('../conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties')
tm = tg.openManagement();
g=tg.traversal();

      PropertyKey pNodeType = createPropertyKey(tm, "nodeType", String.class, Cardinality.SINGLE);
      PropertyKey userContent = createPropertyKey(tm, "storyContent", String.class, Cardinality.SINGLE);
      PropertyKey storyContent = createPropertyKey(tm, "userContent", String.class, Cardinality.SINGLE);

            //"storyContent" : is elasticsearch backend index - mixed
            tm.buildIndex(indexName, Vertex.class).addKey(storyContent, Mapping.TEXTSTRING.asParameter()).ib.addKey(pNodeType, Mapping.TEXTSTRING.asParameter()).buildMixedIndex("search");

            //"userContent" : is elasticsearch backend index - mixed
            tm.buildIndex(indexName, Vertex.class).addKey(userContent, Mapping.TEXTSTRING.asParameter()).ib.addKey(pNodeType, Mapping.TEXTSTRING.asParameter()).buildMixedIndex("search");


            v1= g.addVertex()
            v1.property("nodeType","USER")
            v1.property("userContent" , "dccsdsadas")

            v2= g.addVertex()
            v2.property("nodeType","STORY")
            v2.property("storyContent" , "abdsds")

            v3= g.addVertex()
            v3.property("nodeType","STORY")
            v3.property("storyContent" , "xxxx")              

            v4= g.addVertex()
            v4.property("nodeType","STORY")
            v4.property("storyContent" , "abdsds") , etc'...
```

------------------- EXPECTED RESULT: -----------

I want to return all vertexes with property "storyContent" match text contains prefix , OR all vertexes with property "userContent" matching its case.
in this case return v1 and v2 , because v3 doesn't match and v4 duplicated so it must be ignored by dedup step

```
 g.V().has("storyContent", textContainsPrefix("ab")) "OR" has("userContent", textContainsPrefix("dc"))
```

or maybe :

```
g.V().or(_().has('storyContent', textContainsPrefix("abc")), _().has('userContent', textContainsPrefix("dcc")))
```

PS,

I thought use TP3 OR step with dedup , but gremlin throws error ...

Thanks for any help

Vitaly

Comment: Why didn't the `or()` step work? What did your attempt with `or()` look like? http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#or-step

Comment: g.V().or(_().has('storyContent', textContainsPrefix("abc")), _().has('userContent', textContainsPrefix("dca")))                  , but also i want to add dedup step in order to  ignore duplicate vertexes                                 ---------------------------------------------  the error :  -------------------------------  No signature of method: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.DefaultGraphTraversal.call() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: tail(), wait(), any(), max(), wait(long), each(groovy.lang.Closure)
Display stack trace? [yN]

Comment: Can you update your question with a sample graph and the expected output (in terms of vertices)?

Comment: i've updated my question , thanks ! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something along those lines:

```
g.V().or(
    has('storyContent', textContainsPrefix("abc")),
    has('userContent', textContainsPrefix("dcc"))
)
```

Edit - as mentioned in the comments, this query won't use any index. It must be split into two separate queries.

See TinkerPop v3.0.1 [Drop Step documentation](http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#or-step) and Titan v1.0.0 [Ch. 20 - Index Parameters and Full-Text Search documentation](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/index-parameters.html).

With Titan, you might have to import text predicates before:

```
import static com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.attribute.Text.*
```

`_.()` is TinkerPop2 material and no longer used in TinkerPop3. You now use anonymous traversals as predicates, which sometimes have to start with `__.` for steps named with reserved keywords in Groovy (for ex. `__.in()`).

Comment: thanks man, in gremlin its works but slow , Now i have 2 issues:            

1.     JAVA problem :    GraphTraversalSource g = tg.traversal();
        GraphTraversal t = g.V();

        //it works
        List works = t.has("nodeType", "USER").toList();

        //doesn't , why ?
        List throwsExecption = t.or(t.has("nodeType", "USER"),       t.has("nodeType", "STORY")).toList();    


2. is it other way to make search on different vertexes without using OR step ( due to performance issues) ?

Thanks

Comment: This query won't use any index. To actually use the 2 defined indexes, you'll have to split that into 2 separate queries.

Comment: But if i would create 1 "mixed" search index with both properties as keys , ("storyContent" &"userContent") and then make OR query as in previous step like: ----->   "g.V().or(has('storyContent', textContainsPrefix("abc")), has('userContent', textContainsPrefix("dcc"))),        it would   solve the problem ?

Comment: I edited the answer to take @DanielKuppitz's comment regarding the use of index into account.

Comment: I see thanks , but what is the best way to make query with step condition like:OR,AND using multiple indexes ? I don't want to use direct index query